# Проблема с Json на nodejs сервере

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, nginx, express

У меня на сайте есть платежка от freekassa,которая после оплаты отправляет мне зарос на url оброботчик на котором у меня раюотает nodejs сервер
Если я отправляю запрос на серврер через postman - то все ок,но если это делает платежка я получаю такую ощибку

Сервер на nginx

SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at createStrictSyntaxError (/root/example/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:160:10)
at parse (/root/example/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)

вот код сервера

```
    require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const router = require('./routes/index')
const fs = require('fs');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
const Game = require('./models/Game')
const connectToDb = require('./db');
const paymentController = require('./controllers/paymentController');
//--------//
const app = express()


app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api',router)
app.get('/health-check', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static', { dotfiles: 'allow' }))

//CORS///
app.use(cors())
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

app.post('/pay',paymentController.freekassaPay);
app.post('/paymentstatus',(req,res) => {
 console.log(req.body)
});


const startApp = async () => {
  try{

    connectToDb()

    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
    });

  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}


startApp()
```

Есть идеи?

Comment: интересно. видимо фрикасса посылает в теле запроса строку не в формате json (судя по тексту ожибки первый символ s). попробуйте на все запросы отдавать заголовок Accept, или для парсинга боди использовать не json мидлвару, а urlencoded

Comment: @muturgan Действительно формат был не json,а fromData,Спасибо